# .NET - Passing objects between modules using integration events

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, domain-driven-design

I am working on modular monolith application with DDD approach. I have separated Basket and Order module. I have decided that I want to communicate between modules using events, keep loose coupling between them and independent as much as possible. I am using mediator for publishing events.

In basket module I have CheckoutCommand that finally publishes event BasketCheckedOutEvent.

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CheckoutBasketCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var customerId = _currentUserService.UserId;
        var basket = await _basketRepository.GetBasketByCustomerId(customerId)
            ?? throw new NotFoundException("Basket not found.");

        await _unitOfWork.CommitAndDispatchDomainEventsAsync(basket);
        await _eventDispatcher.PublishAsync(new BasketCheckedOutEvent(basket,
                                                                      command.CouponCode,
                                                                      command.ShippingMethod,
                                                                      command.PaymentMethod));

        
    }
```

Event

```
public record BasketCheckedOutEvent(Basket Basket,
                                    string CouponCode,
                                    int ShippingMethod,
                                    int PaymentMethod) : IEvent
{
}
```

I want the other modules to handle this event, but there are problems. Another module doesnt have access to Basket object (as it is domain object in different module - reasonable). So I can't create an order having basket passed through event.

I am trying to find solution for this. The only one that came to my mind is putting BasketCheckedOutEvent to Shared.Application module and there create a BasketDto - then Dto and Event will be available in Order module and I can proccess it further. In my opinion it doesnt look like a good practise. It creates another layer of abstraction for something really simple in fe. classic monolith.

Passing just basket.Id would be ok (to minimize event size) but then I have to read somehow basket from repository in another module that I cant access to.

Thanks!

Comment: What about passing an `IBasket`? Then each module can have its own representation of a basket.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that passing just `basket.Id` is OK. Both modules, event producer and event subscriber, should have their own repository interfaces to be able to get the basket details from the database. I recommend you to review [MODULAR MONOLITH: A PRIMER](https://www.kamilgrzybek.com/blog/posts/modular-monolith-primer) article and [related github repository](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd).

Comment: This repo and blog is my bible for many weeks :D but i am thinking if showing basket repository in another module is a good practise. Whats more I have repository interfaces in domain layers to keep domain related files/logic together

Comment: Here we can discuss whether your separation is correct or not, i.e. having basket and order in the separate modules. But in general - yes, it's ok to do it like this. It's like having GET http method in microservice. In the github repository you can find exactly such cases when two modules have duplicated db repo interfaces. It's like a client library for microservice.